# Facebook API - Retrieve other sizes picture from attached link

Tags: php, facebook

For the moment, I'm retrieving posts from Facebook account thanks to the endpoint "/account_name/posts".
Some of those posts are links. There is a item "picture", but it's a really bad quality : [example](https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQC-TsT68TnUDum4&w=130&h=130&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ouest-france.fr%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fstyles%2Fimage-900x500%2Fpublic%2F2015%2F08%2F05%2Fles-raisons-de-la-panne-de-ce-mercredi-matin.jpg%3Fitok%3DJ3IVumSQ&cfs=1)

I would like to retrieve a better quality image from this link.
Is it possible, I didn't find the information in the doc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use filed `full_picture`

For example: `me/posts?fields=message,name,link,picture,full_picture`